# json-server Is there anyway to declare anon-CLI middleware

Tags: node.js, json-server

Using json-server , we can declare CLI middlewares

```
You can add your middlewares from the CLI using --middlewares option:

// hello.js
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  res.header('X-Hello', 'World')
   next()
}
json-server db.json --middlewares ./hello.js
json-server db.json --middlewares ./first.js ./second.js
```

But how can I declare an use a json-server middleware in my node.js code ?

I tried to push it into the middleware array

```
 const jsonServer = require('json-server')
 const apiServer = jsonServer.create()  // Returns an Express server for the API
 const apiMiddlewares = jsonServer.defaults() // Returns middlewares used by JSON Server.

 apiMiddlewares.push((req, res, next)  => {
   console.log(new Date(), req.method, req.url)
   next()
 })

 console.log('API MIDDLEWARES ARRAY: ', apiMiddlewares)
```

It's added into the array, but it's never used... no display

Answer (score 0):

Solved by moving my middleware up to the front ...

```
app.use('/api',function(req, res, next){
   console.log('A new request received at ' + Date.now())
   next()
})
```